# Haskell get function run time

Tags: performance, haskell

How can i capture the runtime of a Haskell function, for example, a file Main.hs, compiled with GHC containing a function 'bubbleSort' which sorts items in a list:

```
 bubbleSort :: (Ord t) => [t] -> [t]
 bubbleSort a = loop (length a) bubble a 

 bubble :: (Ord t) => [t] -> [t]
 bubble (a:b:c) | a < b = a : bubble (b:c)
       | otherwise = b : bubble (a:c)
 bubble (a:[]) = [a] 
 bubble [] = []

 loop :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> (t -> t) -> t -> t
 loop num f x | num > 0 =  loop (num-1) f x'
     | otherwise = x
     where x' = f x
```

Note: I am aware this is not the most effective sorting method.

Answer (score 3):

You can try criterion like this,

```
import System.Random
import Data.List
import Criterion.Main
import Criterion.Config


bubbleSort :: (Ord t) => [t] -> [t]
bubbleSort a = loop (length a) bubble a 

loop :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> (t -> t) -> t -> t
loop num f x 
    | num > 0 =  loop (num-1) f x'
    | otherwise = x
        where x' = f x

bubble :: (Ord t) => [t] -> [t]
bubble (a:b:c) | a < b = a : bubble (b:c)
               | otherwise = b : bubble (a:c)
bubble (a:[]) = [a] 
bubble [] = []

randomlist :: Int -> StdGen -> [Int]
randomlist n = take n . unfoldr (Just . random)

main = do 
    seed <- newStdGen 
    let 
        xs100  = randomlist 100  seed  
        xs500  = randomlist 500  seed 
        xs2500 = randomlist 2500 seed 
      in defaultMainWith defaultConfig (return ()) [
            bgroup "bubble" [
                bench "bubble 100"  $ nf bubble xs100
              , bench "bubble 500"  $ nf bubble xs500
              , bench "bubble 2500" $ nf bubble xs2500
              ],
            bgroup "bubble Sort" [
                bench "bubbleSort 100"  $ nf bubbleSort xs100
              , bench "bubbleSort 500"  $ nf bubbleSort xs500
              , bench "bubbleSort 2500" $ nf bubbleSort xs2500
              ]
            ]
```

And the output,

```
warming up
estimating clock resolution...
mean is 2.181457 us (320001 iterations)
found 41466 outliers among 319999 samples (13.0%)
  2428 (0.8%) low severe
  39038 (12.2%) high severe
estimating cost of a clock call...
mean is 105.7764 ns (13 iterations)

benchmarking bubble/bubble 100
mean: 5.174493 us, lb 5.158926 us, ub 5.190592 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 80.64570 ns, lb 70.99540 ns, ub 93.12886 ns, ci 0.950
variance introduced by outliers: 8.479%
variance is slightly inflated by outliers

benchmarking bubble/bubble 500
mean: 28.41568 us, lb 28.22828 us, ub 28.64927 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 1.071815 us, lb 843.6888 ns, ub 1.531296 us, ci 0.950
found 4 outliers among 100 samples (4.0%)
  2 (2.0%) high mild
  1 (1.0%) high severe
variance introduced by outliers: 34.577%
variance is moderately inflated by outliers

benchmarking bubble/bubble 2500
mean: 132.3620 us, lb 131.0149 us, ub 134.1072 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 7.802474 us, lb 6.333342 us, ub 11.58801 us, ci 0.950
found 1 outliers among 100 samples (1.0%)
  1 (1.0%) high severe
variance introduced by outliers: 56.487%
variance is severely inflated by outliers

benchmarking bubble Sort/bubbleSort 100
mean: 399.7690 us, lb 398.7208 us, ub 400.7847 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 5.291009 us, lb 4.761788 us, ub 5.961798 us, ci 0.950
variance introduced by outliers: 6.563%
variance is slightly inflated by outliers

benchmarking bubble Sort/bubbleSort 500
mean: 15.42273 ms, lb 15.26078 ms, ub 15.60196 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 872.8984 us, lb 784.0365 us, ub 967.8269 us, ci 0.950
variance introduced by outliers: 54.470%
variance is severely inflated by outliers

benchmarking bubble Sort/bubbleSort 2500
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 48.56091 s
mean: 473.5322 ms, lb 472.0005 ms, ub 474.9877 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 7.695022 ms, lb 6.700990 ms, ub 9.001423 ms, ci 0.950
found 2 outliers among 100 samples (2.0%)
  2 (2.0%) low mild
variance introduced by outliers: 9.408%
variance is slightly inflated by outliers
```

Comment: For `bubbleSort`, indeed `whnf` is sufficient. But for `bubble`, it only forces one comparison (and maybe swap). Generally, when benchmarking functions with list results, you need `nf`.

Comment: why "collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 29.32801 s" appears only once, under "benchmarking bubble Sort/bubbleSort 2500"? strange...

Comment: @WillNess The others are fast, criterion only says that if the estimated time is long enough (don't remember exactly how long, 3 seconds or 5, something like that).

Comment: now the only thing that's missing is `map (logBase 5) [257.38/8.837, 8.837/0.2085]` => `[2.095, 2.328]`. BTW, do you have control over the number of runs? 100 runs for the 2500 case is not needed; 20 would be enough; for 5000 I'd be fine with 10 - even at the cost of increased deviation.

Comment: Will maybe because in the other case the computation as so short that no correct estimation of global run could be calculated. @Daniel I going to update my post with nf as after a rerun the result are more consistent

Comment: @WillNess You can specify the number of samples, but only for all benchmarks, `-s 50` e.g.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks to you both; that's the room for improvement then; what wold be *really* cool is to have the tables like I did manually for http://ideone.com/p0e81, created automatically, first with fewer samples (and larger deviation), then improved gradually...

Comment: ... with new data, for bubbleSort, `map (logBase 5) [473.53/ 15.42, 15.42/0.4] :: [Float] ==> [2.1277926,2.2690878]`, i.e. `~ n^2.1..2.3`. for bubble, `map (logBase 5) [132.36/28.42, 28.42/5.175] ==> [0.96, 1.06]`, i.e. `~ n^1.0..1.1`. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, least sophisticated method is, first compile your file with `ghc --make yourfile.hs`, then run it at your shell *⁄* command prompt as `> yourfile +RTS -s` and examine the statistics printout.

The file should start with

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}

module Main 
where
```

and contain one `main` value of type `IO ()`, for example

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ bubbleSort ([1..50]++[42])
```

To get any meaningful reading from this, you should find out the [empirical orders of growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) for your algorithm; just one datapoint isn't going to tell you much.

Comment: is there any way to get it to go into a more detailed time measurement?. For example, if the time is under a second?

Comment: @user2214957 you can run it 10 or 100 times, and time it by means of your shell (without -RTS +s); or increase the size of data to achieve longer execution times. That's what I meant by "least sophisticated" ... :)